# laravel-datatable: I can't go through the collection

Tags: javascript, laravel, datatable, datatables

I have the following collection in this format

```
[
{
activitydate: "2019-07-08",
producidos: 1693,
muertos: 0,
propagados: 2,
stock: 1691
},
{
activitydate: "2019-07-05",
producidos: 18,
muertos: 0,
propagados: 0,
stock: 18
},
{
activitydate: "2019-07-04",
producidos: 14,
muertos: 0,
propagados: 0,
stock: 14
}
]
```

this is the code of my controller and datatable

```
$final_c=collect();
....
.....
...
    $final_c->push([
    "activitydate"=>$key,
    "producidos"=>$producidos,
    "muertos"=>$muertos,
    "propagados"=>$propagados,
    "stock"=>$stock
    ]);
    }

          return $this->ajax($final_c);

          public function ajax($activity)
        {
            return Datatables::of($activity)


                ->addColumn('activitydate',function($activity)
                {
                    return $activity->activitydate;
                })
                ->addColumn('producidos',function($activity)
                {
                    return $activity->producidos;
                })
                ->addColumn('muertos',function($activity)
                {
                    return $activity->muertos;

                })

                ->addColumn('propagados',function($activity)
                {

                    return $activity->propagados;

                })

                ->addColumn('stock',function($activity)
                {
                    return $activity->stock;

                })->rawColumns(['activitydate','producidos','muertos','propagados','stock'])->make(true);
        }
```

javascript code

```
    function makeColumns()
        {
            return [
                { data: 'activitydate',    className: "text-center" , orderable: false, searchable: false},
                { data: 'producidos',    className: "text-center"      },
                { data: 'muertos',    className: "text-center"        },
                { data: 'propagados',    className: "text-center"       },
                { data: 'stock',    className: "text-center"      },

            ];
        }

$('#up_table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax:{
            url:"/api/up-table/dt",

        },
        columns: makeColumns(),
        language: {
            search: "_INPUT_",
            searchPlaceholder: "BUSCAR..."
        },
        "lengthMenu": [[ 50,10, 20, 40, 80, 160,-1 ],[ 'Elegir','10', '20', '40', '80', '160','Todo']],
        /*initComplete: function()
        {
            this.api().columns().every(
                function()
                {
                    var column = this;
                    //added class "select"
                    var select = $('<select class="select" multiple="multiple" PlaceHolder="SELECCIONAR"><option value=""></option></select>')
                        .appendTo($(column.footer())
                            .empty())
                        .on('change', function()
                        {
                            var vals = $('option:selected', this).map(function(index, element) {
                                return $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(element).val());
                            }).toArray().join('|');

                            column  .search(vals.length > 0 ? '' + vals + '' : '', true, false)
                                .draw();
                        });

                    column  .data()
                        .unique()
                        .sort()
                        .each(function(d, j)
                        {
                            select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                        });
                });
            //select2 init for .select class
            $(".select").select2();
        }*/
    });
```

when I try to go through it I get

> Exception Message:↵↵Trying to get property of non-object

However, if I change the way I go through the values ​​in my datatable, I get the following

code changed

```
  public function ajax($activity)
{
    return Datatables::of($activity)


        ->addColumn('activitydate',function($activity)
        {
            return $activity["activitydate"];
        })
        ->addColumn('producidos',function($activity)
        {
            return $activity["producidos"];
        })
        ->addColumn('muertos',function($activity)
        {
            return $activity["muertos"];

        })

        ->addColumn('propagados',function($activity)
        {

            return $activity["propagados"];

        })

        ->addColumn('stock',function($activity)
        {
            return $activity["stock"];

        })->rawColumns(['activitydate','producidos','muertos','propagados','stock'])->make(true);
}
```

> DataTables warning: table id=up_table - Requested unknown parameter 'id' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please

and in my network tab I can see the data obtained, which is the following

```
{draw: 1, recordsTotal: 3, recordsFiltered: 3,…}
data: [{activitydate: "2019-07-08", producidos: 1693, muertos: 0, propagados: 2, stock: 1691},…]
0: {activitydate: "2019-07-08", producidos: 1693, muertos: 0, propagados: 2, stock: 1691}
1: {activitydate: "2019-07-05", producidos: 18, muertos: 0, propagados: 0, stock: 18}
2: {activitydate: "2019-07-04", producidos: 14, muertos: 0, propagados: 0, stock: 14}
draw: 1
input: {draw: "1", columns: [{data: "id", name: null, searchable: "false", orderable: "false",…},…],…}
recordsFiltered: 3
recordsTotal: 3
```

What kind of format does the datatable need to work?

Comment: Can you please show the javascript you use to make the table?

Comment: hi @NMahurin I've edited my question

Comment: I've ran into that row 0,col 0 error a few times. Does your html have 5 `<th>` elements? Also post the table HTML. There is probably some difference with the table layout and what Datatables expects.